# Difference between gauge and partition in Integration Theory

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partitions-for-integration

I'm studying generalized Riemann integral using Bartle's Introduction to Real Analysis textbook.

What's the difference between gauge and partition? Seems like the same concept to me.

Comment: Are you talking about the [gauge integral](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/ccc/gauge/)?

Answer (score 0):

The gauge is the maximum of the lengths of the partition subintervals of the partition.